# How to prevent that members can create tags in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-for-teams

At the moment the number of tags is growing significantly in Stack Overflow for Teams.

In the public Stack Overflow one requires a reputation of at least 300 points to create tags, but in Teams everybody can create tags.

> Creating the new tag 'dsfgdfhds' requires at least 300 reputation. Try
>   something from the existing tags list instead.

[image]

How to prevent this?

Comment: Well in teams it is a private environment where people are approved to be a part of and that is why everything is more open unlike the public stack exchange sites where anyone can join. At least that is my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to prevent this at present as the rep requirement is set to 1 (which all users meet). This means that the SE team has to add this as a feature which takes dev time. Its ultimately up to them (and therefore the community who convince the devs that this is a needed feature) to implement such a feature.

Comment: Should I create a feature request somewhere else or is there something else I can do to raise awareness?

Comment: @030 Leave the feature request right her. If you are a Team Admin or want to try you can [file a ticket](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/tickets/new) to try to bring that to the attention of the developer team.